# PowerShell Pipeline iteration

Tags: powershell

I often write functions that need to accept pipelines like:

```
function Invoke-ExchangeHubChecks
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [object[]]$oServersToTest,
        [int]$QueueWarnThreshold = 50,
        [int]$QueueFailThreshold = 100

    )
    begin
    {
        $oHubTests = @()
        $c=0
    }
    Process
    {
        $c++
        $Server = $oServersToTest[0] 

        $oHubTests += [pscustomobject]@{
            Identity = $server.Identity
            Queue = "blah" 
            Count = $c
        }
    }
    end
    {
        $oHubTests
    }
}
    end
    {
        $oHubTests
    }
}
```

I often see code snippets with a foreach inside the process block. My understanding is that the process block replaces the need for the foreach block (in most cases).

I need to add a "filter" to the input object "$oServersToTest". I have used "where-object" to create the filter:

```
$Server = $oServersToTest[0] | Where-Object {$_.IsHub}
```

However, as it iterates over the collection, it is adding objects that don't match the where clause to the custom object, proved by $c:

Output:

```
Identity    Queue Count
--------    ----- -----
Server01    blah      1
Server02    blah      2
Server03    blah      3
Server04    blah      4
Server05    blah      5
            blah      6
            blah      7
Server06    blah      8
Server07    blah      9
Server08    blah     10
Server09    blah     11
Server10    blah     12
            blah     13
            blah     14
```

Is this an example where I must use a foreach inside the process block:

```
Process
{
    $c++
    #$Server = $oServersToTest[0] | Where-Object{$_.IsHubServer}
    $TestResult = @()
    $oServersToTest | Where-Object {$_.IsHubServer} | Foreach-object{
        $TestResult += [pscustomobject]@{
            Identity = $_.Identity
            Queue = "blah" 
            Count = $c
        }
    }

    $oHubTests += $TestResult
}
End
{
    $oHubTests
}
```

Which works, but why does this work and not the other way? To me, it's doing twice the work.

(Powershell 5.0)

TIA

Comment: In most cases, a `ForEach` inside a `PROCESS` block is to allow the filter/function to be used both as a cmdlet (`Do-MyStuff -ComputerName A,B,C`) and as a filter in the pipeline (`Retrieve-Computers | Do-MyStuff`). This works because if `$ComputerName` is declared as `[String[]]` and is only passed a single computer name, it gets coerced into an array with only one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `foreach()` loop inside the `process` block.

As [Jeff Zeitlin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230413/powershell-pipeline-iteration#comment73530967_43230413), this also lets you support processing of collections with *named parameters* and pipelining alike.

The reason for using `foreach()` over `ForEach-Object` is three-fold:

1. Performance:
   When the input collection is already in memory (which it is in both cases), the overhead from implicit parameter binding will make `ForEach-Object` slower than `foreach()`
2. Readability:
   IMO, having a named variable (like `$Server`) makes the script more readable and you avoid confusion with nested `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object` clauses inside the loop
3. Functionality:
   With a plain ol' `foreach()`, you get fast flow control options like `break` and `continue` for free.

---

```
process {
    $oHubTests += foreach($server in $oServersToTest |Where-Object {$_.IsHubServer}){
        $c++
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Identity = $server.Identity
            Queue = "blah" 
            Count = $c
        }
    }
}
```

If the only thing your cmdlet does is take the input and construct corresponding `[pscustomobject]`'s, then I would cut out the `$oHubTests` part completely, and just output the objects as they flow through:

```
function Invoke-ExchangeHubChecks
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [object[]]$oServersToTest,
        [int]$QueueWarnThreshold = 50,
        [int]$QueueFailThreshold = 100

    )
    begin {
        $c=0
    }
    process {
        foreach($server in $oServersToTest |Where-Object {$_.IsHubServer}){
            $c++
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Identity = $server.Identity
                Queue = "blah" 
                Count = $c
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing one of the most complicated design structures of powershell for me. Creating a cmdlet that can process an array of objects as provided as a parameter or per item piped into the cmdlet.

For example `do-something -input $items` or `$items | do-something`.

The process block is meant mostly for when a cmdlet accept pipeline values. It doesn't replace the for loop as you think it. The pipe has already done an implicit loop on the collection although that is not 100% accurate but that is a different story. I'll continue with this somehow inaccurate statement for simplicity.

With such cases, the `begin`,`process` and `end` allow you to control what happens at each part of the pipe or imaginary loop. `Before` and `end` are executed only once and can used for initialization and finalizing. In the above example first `begin` executed, then `process` for each item piped from the collection and then `end`.  But if the collection is used as a normal parameter then it's `begin`, `process` with a loop inside and then `end`.

I understand that is complicated but try to visualize with a `do-something` implementation that just writes to the host what is going on.

I had to understand this sequence when developing [MarkdownPS](https://github.com/Sarafian/MarkdownPS/). Check this [example](https://github.com/Sarafian/MarkdownPS/blob/master/Modules/MarkdownPS/New-MDList.ps1) and the examples of usage on the root. `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name | New-MDList`. FYI the last example is a demonstration of the inaccurate statement I used in this answer.